# RegExp constructor escapes slash character but not dot

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Say I have this:

```
console.log(new RegExp('.git'));
console.log(new RegExp('scripts/npm'));
```

the results are:

```
/.git/
/scripts\/npm/
```

my question is - why does it escape the slash in scripts/npm, but it does not escape the . in .git? What is the rhyme and reason to that?

**Note, in this case**, the regex strings are being passed from the command line, so I need to convert them to regex using RegExp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An unescaped `/` denotes the beginning and end of a regular expression. When you pass in a string containing `/` into the constructor, of course that `/` is *part* of the regular expression, not a symbol denoting the beginning or end.

The `.` is something else entirely, and has nothing to RE delimiters, so it's left as-is.

Note that if you want the regular expression to match a *literal* dot (rather than any character), you need to double-escape it when using the constructor:

```
console.log(new RegExp('\\.git'));
```

Comment: Just to clarify the double escape - you need that because you're passing a *string* and when you do, a `\.` is converted into just `.` which means "any character" to the regex. Writing `\\.` results in a string containing a single backslash so *the regex* pattern now contains `\.` or "only match a dot". If using the literal regex constructor, then `/\./` is equivalent to `new RegExp("\\.")` - the former is not a string, so it doesn't need the backslash to be escaped like with the latter approach.

Answer (score 0):

When you write regex in JS you can initialize regex strings using two `/`. This is called regular expression literal initialization. More about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

For instance

```
let re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
```

Now, for the question why does it append `\` before `/`, it is simply due to the way `RegExp` processes the passed string literal. This prevents the passed string from becoming corrupt ensuring all passed characters are accounted. 
Furthermore if you examine the object returned by the `RegExp`, we can see that the actual source attribute is set to `scripts\\/npm`. So, the first `\` indicates literal significance of the second `\`. Whilst from regular expressions perspective `\`, it simply escapes the proceeding `/` to form regular expression literal notation.

Comment: **Note, in this case**, the regex strings are being passed from the command line, so I need to convert them from string to regex using RegExp. I updated the OP to reflect this requirement.

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman understood, the output you are getting is simply the literal version. I assume, the RegExp simply wraps any special characters with `\` to ensure input remains true to what you've entered initially.